# Jquery => toUTCString() returns 1 day back date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, utc

I need to get format like below

**19 Aug 2015 04:22:36 GMT**

I have following code

```
var dt = '2015-08-19 04:22:36';
alert(new Date(dt).toUTCString().substr(4))
```

It returns me

**18 Aug 2015 22:52:36 GMT**

where as it should return

**19 Aug 2015 22:52:36 GMT**

What is wrong in my code

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/0a3m59v1/)

As per answers below it seems it's converting the date to UTC date time.

I have date in UTC format in database. So please if some one could suggest the desired format without using toUTCString()

**Update**

Tried following

```
var dt = '2015-08-19 04:22:36  UTC';

alert(new Date(dt).toUTCString().substr(4))
```

It gives me liddate in FireFox and IE, chrome it is fine

**Solved changed date string to**

```
var dt = '2015/08/19 04:22:36  UTC';
```

Thanks

Comment: Your output is looking correct !!

Comment: @Jake745 , I have uploaded on server i.e. US server, that still showing same, what fiddle results at your end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toUTCString()` converts your date to UTC so the outcome is correct!
Change your string to this `var dt = '2015-08-19 04:22:36 UTC';` (notice the **UTC**)

or use the `Date.UTC()` function:

```
alert(new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 09, 19, 04, 22, 36)).toUTCString().substr(4))
```

Notice that the month is 0 based (0 -11) so to get August 
you need to increase your monty by 1

Comment: I have --2015-08-19 04:22:36-- in database, the date is already a UTC date, now i have to just show   --19 Aug 2015 4:22:36 GMT--

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam have you tried adding a 'UTC' to your date string? If you don't say that the date is in utc javascript will assume it's in your local time

Comment: jsfiddle.net/0a3m59v1/1 -> var dt = '2015-08-19 04:22:36 UTC'; it returns me lid date in firefox and wrong date in IE

Answer (score 1):

From your profile, I can see you are 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of UTC, so the `var dt = '2015-08-19 04:22:36';` returns a Date object which is 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead of UTC time i.e. your local time. When you convert this date to UTC, it subtracts 5.5 hours and returns the Date object which is 22:56 previous night. The time part `04:22:36` is actually 4:22 a.m. or 4:22 a.m. at morning.

Comment: But I have uploaded on server i.e. US server, that still showing same, what fiddle results at your end?

Comment: I am from the same City :-)

Comment: The Date object is created inside the browser, so it will always take the local time. Try using Adam's answer, or append " GMT+0" to your dt variable.